# Copy a file between two Ubuntu instances

Tags: 16.04, ssh, root, scp

I have two Ubuntu instances running on two different virutal nodes (Docker). I want to copy a file from one node to another quite a few times from my python script. For now, I am testing with `scp` if the other machine is accessible. Both machines can `ping` each other but the problem is `scp` of ssh not working.

I have tried:

1. Both of the machines are virtual and copy of the `ssh` files not possible - so in future ssh certificates can be used.
2. `scp` doesnot work because it asks for password, when I give `root` password, gives `invalid password` error.

Please help me with some pointers which allows me to copy a file from one machine to another.

**EDIT**

`scp` command: `scp sourcefile.txt root@xxx.xxx.xxx:/root/dev`

P.S. Apologies if there is some very basic solution for this and I cannot see it, I am new to this setup.

Comment: yes, it is asking password for the target container, but when I enter password it says invalid password? Although I have enabled password with `passwd root`  and `passwd -u root`

Comment: @user535733 done.

Comment: Are you using 14.04?

Comment: sorry I am using 16.04

Comment: added the procedure to get root working for a short time, now I seen your edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the ssh keys on the instance1 then in the `/home/username/.ssh` or `/root/.ssh` directory there will be a file called the `id_rsa.pub`. Take this file and copy its contents into the `authorized_keys` file (creating it most likely) in the other instance2 directory, reverse the procedure for the instance2 `.pub` file to instance1. Once done you have passwordless copying in place. This works for any account.

Without access to anything except side by side on screen or written to paper for it. Then opening of the `.id_rsa.pub` and writing it into the mentioned file `authorized_keys`. Once done in instance2 then you can copy it back from them to your  `authorized_keys` file, their `.id_rsa.pub`
There is a good amount of characters to copy and everything you see needs to be copied over into the other file exactly as it appears. On one long single line that starts with the.

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc
```

For example the start of my public key file.

Root is always disabled now I see this in your edit. You need to login as normal user then use sudo or su to become root to do anything as root. `#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` needs to be Yes in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to allow it access. Then only for the time to get a /root/.ssh/authorized_keys file in place to allow the key method to be used. You need to restart the ssh `service sshd restart` both times you edit the file once when enabling and the second when you disable as soon as possible, **namely immediately** upon the key file put in place and a logout and back in with it confirms it works.

Comment: my both instances are in a simulation envoirnent with no external connectivity, how can I copy them?

Comment: Thanks @HappyTux, I  managed to copy keys both sides but still it is asking for password.

Comment: You are sure you never made a typo? use the `ssh -vvvv ....` as the start of the command to get some debugging info and to see what it does when connecting.

Comment: checked. no typo